# Android Trackball Coordinates Issue in Open GL Surface View

Tags: android, opengl-es

We are working on TrackBall Events to draw lines,shapes in `OpenGL` but it not working properly. We have tired to implement Trackball event in Canvas and its working fine. But TrackBall events not working in OpenGL `GLSurfaceView`. But we can able to draw lines using Touch Event. please guide me to implement in Trackball event.

Canvas Code:

```
@Override 
public boolean onTrackballEvent (MotionEvent motionEvent) 
{ 

        int action = motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;     
        float scaleX = motionEvent.getXPrecision()* TRACKBALL_SCALE ;
        float scaleY = motionEvent.getYPrecision()* TRACKBALL_SCALE;
        int N = motionEvent.getHistorySize();

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {            
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

          mCurX += motionEvent.getRawX() * scaleX;
             mCurY += motionEvent.getRawY() * scaleY;

         for (int i=0; i<N; i++) { 
          Log.i("ACTION_MOVE", "N="+N);   
                mCurX += motionEvent.getHistoricalX(i) * scaleX;   
                mCurY += motionEvent.getHistoricalY(i) * scaleY;
                touch_move(mCurX, mCurY);
            }             
          touch_move(mCurX,mCurY);
            invalidate();
            break;            
    }            
}
```

OpenGL Code:

```
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

@Override 
 public CustomGLView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        this.mContext = context;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), 
    new GestureListener(context));
        setupOpenGL();
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onTrackballEvent (MotionEvent motionEvent) 

{           
        int fingers = motionEvent.getPointerCount();
        GestureHandler.getInstance().mGestureMotionEventHistory.put(motionEvent.getAction(), motionEvent);
       for(int i = 0; i < fingers; i ++) {
            MotionEvent.PointerCoords coords = 
    new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
            motionEvent.getPointerCoords(i, coords);
            GestureHandler.getInstance().setGesturePointerNumAndLocation(i, coords.x, coords.y);
     GestureHandler.getInstance().mXYPointerCoordsByIndex.put(i, 
        new float[]{coords.x, coords.y});
        }  
  mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);  
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why is there a `break` in your `onTrackballEvent`?

Comment: in `onTrackballEvent` we are using switch case statement for that break, it's not a problem. @SuperBiasedMan